# Laravel book a model id, then cleanup if not used

Tags: laravel, promise, queue

I would like to book a model id, the payment id, during the purchase flow.
If the user completes the purchase, then the model must be updated with the correct details.
If not, the model must be discarded.
**What would be the best approach?** In this way I'm going to waste a lot of payment IDs, as MySQL will keep on incrementing the ID even if the previous one has been deleted.

So far, I'm using an Ajax call to retrieve the model id. The controller calls a service which creates an "empty" payment model, then produces a json response. This part works, now I have to cleanup the unfulfilled payments.

```
public static function book_id (int $user_id): int
{
    $payment = Payment::withoutEvents(function () use ($user_id) { // create without triggering the observer
        return Payment::create([
            'user_id'       => $user_id,
            //etc.
        ]);
    });

    ClearPayment::dispatch( $payment )->delay( now()->addMinutes(30) );
    
    return $payment->id;
}
```

My idea for cleaning up the "empty" payment records from the DB, is to enqueue a delayed cleanup job. Then if the purchase goes through, the job must be removed from the queue. (but I never worked with queues before)

OR I could just add a cleanup task which runs everyday.

All advice is welcome

Comment: You need a “lock”. Try google “laravel redis lock”

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it, but I'm not using Redis

Comment: Lock can be obtain in other ways, it more pattern than technology.

Comment: I'm looking at the Laravel documentation. It uses locks to create unique jobs (I do not want unique jobs, I need concurrent jobs). And doesn't mention anything about removing a specific job from a queue. Can it even be done?

Comment: You can go with session about it. After some time, discard what is in session (in case payment wasn't made).

Comment: Quick tip not related to what your question is, if you want to use `create` but without events, you can use `Payment::createQuietely(...)`

Comment: @matiaslauriti are you sure? `Call to undefined method App\\Models\\Payment::createQuietly()` (same goes for createQuietely, which is spelled wrong)

Comment: @Valentino 100%, check it on the official doc: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method

Comment: @matiaslauriti ok, I'm on Laravel 9

Comment: That is why then, it is important that you mention what Larave version you are using or put the right tag like [tag:laravel-9], but you now know in L10 you can use it